# Iterate through a column for duplicates, append a number to duplicate column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, append, iteration

I have a large data frame with a column of 78,000 names. I want to go through the column, compare the names in one row to another, and if there are duplicates, I want to append a number to all duplicate values, starting with 1,2,3, etc.

```
df <- data.frame("Promoter"=c("Xkr4_promoter", 
                              "Gm18956_promoter", 
                              "Gm19938_promoter", 
                              "Gm37381_promoter", "Gm37381_promoter", 
                              "Rp1_promoter", "Rp1_promoter", 
                              "Gm6101_promoter", 
                              "Gm37483_promoter",  
                              "Sox17_promoter", "Sox17_promoter", "Sox17_promoter", "Sox17_promoter"))
```

Starting data:

| Promoter |
| --- |
| Xkr4_promoter |
| Gm18956_promoter |
| Gm19938_promoter |
| Gm37381_promoter |
| Gm37381_promoter |
| Rp1_promoter |
| Rp1_promoter |
| Gm6101_promoter |
| Gm37483_promoter |
| Sox17_promoter |
| Sox17_promoter |
| Sox17_promoter |
| Sox17_promoter |

Expected output data:

| Promoter |
| --- |
| Xkr4_promoter |
| Gm18956_promoter |
| Gm19938_promoter |
| Gm37381_promoter_1 |
| Gm37381_promoter_2 |
| Rp1_promoter_1 |
| Rp1_promoter_2 |
| Gm6101_promoter |
| Gm37483_promoter |
| Sox17_promoter_1 |
| Sox17_promoter_2 |
| Sox17_promoter_3 |
| Sox17_promoter_4 |

I have tried multiple variations of `for loops`, where I tried to compare the values and if they were the same, add to a count and then `paste()` the count to the value in the column. See below my most recent attempt:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  count <- 0
  if ((df[i,1] == lag(df[i,1]))) {
  count <- count+1
  df$Promoter <- paste(df[i,1], count, sep=".")
  }
  else {
    count <- 0
  }
}
```

However I end up with this error that I haven't figured out how to solve:
`Error in if ((df[i, 1] == lag(df[i, 1]))) { :missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I think I might need to use `mutate()` in `dplyr`, using `lead()` or `lag()` but I haven't quite figured out how to put them into a working order.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: There might be an argument for storing the duplicate(s) info in its own column rather than appending as appending makes each seemingly unique. Depends on what you anticipate doing next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R supports vectorised functions, so usually you can get away with not implementing a for-loop.

A possible approach is identifying duplicates with `duplicated()`, calculating the cumulative sum of this, and then pasting this integer to the original `Promoter`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
        mutate(dupl = if_else(duplicated(Promoter), 1, 0)) |> 
        group_by(Promoter) |> 
        mutate(dupl = cumsum(dupl),
               Promoter = paste(Promoter, dupl, sep = "_")) |> 
        select(-dupl)
```

Output

```r
#> # A tibble: 13 x 1
#> # Groups:   Promoter [13]
#>    Promoter          
#>    <chr>             
#>  1 Xkr4_promoter_0   
#>  2 Gm18956_promoter_0
#>  3 Gm19938_promoter_0
#>  4 Gm37381_promoter_0
#>  5 Gm37381_promoter_1
#>  6 Rp1_promoter_0    
#>  7 Rp1_promoter_1    
#>  8 Gm6101_promoter_0 
#>  9 Gm37483_promoter_0
#> 10 Sox17_promoter_0  
#> 11 Sox17_promoter_1  
#> 12 Sox17_promoter_2  
#> 13 Sox17_promoter_3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much! This is perfect. I know for loops aren't ideal for R, that's why i'm trying to find other ways to work around it but I haven't gotten the language down yet.

Comment: @ispeakcat I really recommend R for Data Science if you haven't come across it yet: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html